# jpa annotation can not create table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, entity

when i define a Entity Object like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dau")
public class EntityDau implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    private String startday;
    @Id
    private String endday; 
    @Id
    private String serverid;
    @Id
    private String channelid;
    @Id
    private String platformid;
    private int dau;

    ......

}
```

the table dau can not create in my mysql db.

but when i delete a @Id, it is success, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dau")
public class EntityDau implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    private String startday;
    @Id
    private String endday; 
    @Id
    private String serverid;
    @Id
    private String channelid;
    private String platformid;
    private int dau;

    ......

}
```

The difference only a @id. Is there a limit on the number of @id annotation in JPA/Hibernate ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As any basic JPA documentation would tell you, if you have a single `@Id` then the id is fully defined, BUT if you have multiple `@Id` (i.e composite id) then you must define an `@IdClass`. I would expect error messages out of the JPA implementation to tell you that, and the implementation I use certainly does with its exceptions.

See also http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/application_identity.html

Comment: No. The second example is successed. It can create the table

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't be able to "create the schema". What I did say is that you NEED @IdClass to use JPA. You will get to runtime and fail with that as it is.